# Why sign me out instead of sign in when I run Python/selenium code to log in to apple gsx website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to log in to Apple GSX site using my automated python/selenium code. Everything works accordingly until it clicks on the sign on. When it does that Apple GSX site signs me out, it will not sign in. Can anybody please tell me what's wrong with my code and how to fix it? (I am new to python, not sure whats wrong with it)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path =  r"C:\#TestWork\gsx\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

driver.get("https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/classicLogin.html?appIdKey=45571f444c4f547116bfd052461b0b3ab1bc2b445a72138157ea8c5c82fed623")

username = driver.find_element_by_id("accountname")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("accountpassword")

username.send_keys("testdanzi@gmail.com")
password.send_keys("********")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="signInHyperLink"]""").click()
```

Before sign in - 
[image]
After
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are [not apple support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have credentials , but still you can try with this code :

```
driver.get("https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/classicLogin.html?appIdKey=45571f444c4f547116bfd052461b0b3ab1bc2b445a72138157ea8c5c82fed623") 

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "accountname"))).send_keys("username")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "accountpassword"))).send_keys("password")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "signInHyperLink"))).click()
```

Note that you would have to import :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: @PrasadD : Check with this code and let us know the status.

Comment: I did what you said, still the same. Its just log out as previously. nothing different. Thank you so much for your help and time.

Comment: `
driver.get("https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/classicLogin.html?appIdKey=45571f444c4f547116bfd052461b0b3ab1bc2b445a72138157ea8c5c82fed623") 

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "accountname"))).send_keys("testdanzi@gmail.com")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "accountpassword"))).send_keys("********")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "signInHyperLink"))).click() `

Comment: I can't validate it,since I do not have credentials.

Comment: I found the problem, when I use the address like this https://idmsa.apple.com , it works. Again thank you.